# data-equalizer outputting "height: inherit"

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I have been trying to get some boxes to equalise in height using the data equalizer but so far it only applies a height: inherit class rather than the required pixel height. This is the code I'm trying to equalise:

```html
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
  @foreach($category_items as $row)
  <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-12 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
    <div class="small-12 columns">
      <h5>{{{ $row['name'] }}}</h5>
      <p>{{ strip_tags($row['description']) }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding_left_small" align="left">
      <button>View Range</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

The foreach loops about 12 times, and the data in the "name" and "description" vary in length. Any help would be appreciated
Thanks
Stephen

Comment: Which part of this are you trying to equalize? You need to have at least two elements to equalize.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, The foreach loops 12 times, and the loops output is all contained within the row with data-equalizer on, so when the scrip is run, and all the HTML is output, there are 12 divs watching and are all contained within the data-equalizer row at the top.

Comment: Can you add the html after the foreach loop runs?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at [CSS flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).
If you give the container this style:

```
.row-container { 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: stretch; 
}
```

Avoid using `.row`, as foundation adds `.row:before { content: " ";}` which messes with flexbox. You don't need the `.row` :)

All items will stretch out to match the tallest one.
Easy peasy with flexbox. :)

Some useful resources:

#### [Guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox)

#### [Play with flexboxes live](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties)